# Are you healed if you play Reno Jackson in fatigue?

Tags: hearthstone

This is the new card Reno Jackson introduced in the League of Explorers expansion for Hearthstone:
[image: Reno Jackson]

What would happen if Reno Jackson is played in fatigue, as there are no cards for there to be one of?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the wording on the battlecry, I would say you are healed, because your deck contains "no more than 1 of any card". Zero is less than one, ergo you are healed. Even if your deck is "empty", it is still considered a deck, so reno still checks it.

[image]
Here are larger [versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dozsm.jpg)

Comment: Have you actually tested this?

Comment: @Sorean I've tested it now.

Comment: Excellent, that's what makes a good answer. =D I'd edit it to put the image in the answer itself in case the imgur link dies.

Comment: I always read it as referring to your **full** deck, for some reason.  So if you had *any* duplicate cards at all, there was no point to having him.  This makes much more sense.

Comment: @Bobson Yup, many Reno decks use 1 or 2 duplicates, trading off the inconsistency of being able to use Reno early for the power of those cards (Molten Giants, for instance, in Reno-Lock).